# Trying to Build Fully Left-Skewed Binary Tree - Getting Stack Overflow Error

Tags: java, binary-tree, stack-overflow

I can't figure out why my recursive call here is bad. Could someone please shed some light on what I am doing wrong and how I can correct this? I appreciate any and all help.

I have an array filled with random integers am trying to build a fully left-skewed binary tree.

Main:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        //Declare New Array to Store Integer Values
        int[] array1 = new int[26];
        randArray(array1, 1, 50);

        for(int x=0; x < array1.length; x++)
            System.out.print(array1[x] + " ");

        //Build Skewed Tree
        BinaryTree tree1 = new BinaryTree(array1[0]);
        for(int x=1; x < array1.length; x++)
            tree1.addLeft(new BinaryTree(array1[x]));

        tree1.print();


    }

    public static void randArray(int[] list, int low, int up) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            list[i] = rand.nextInt(up - low + 1) + low;
        }
    }
}
```

addLeft:

```
  public void addLeft(BinaryTree subtree){
        if(leftChild != null){
            addLeft(leftChild);
        }

        leftChild = subtree;
    }
```

Comment: The addLeft method looks suspicious. If (leftChild != null) it will be so in the recursive call as well and you will get an endless loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your addLeft function should look like this:

```
public void addLeft(BinaryTree subtree){
   if(leftChild != null){
      leftChild.addLeft(subtree);
   }

   leftChild = subtree;
}
```

Note: this doesn't actually sort anything.  If you want a sorted left skewed binary tree the function should look (something) like this:

```
public void addLeft(BinaryTree subtree){
   if (subtree.value < value)
   {
      int tmp = value;
      value = subtree.value;
      subtree.value = tmp;
   }

   if(leftChild != null){
      leftChild.addLeft(subtree);
   }

   leftChild = subtree;
}
```

I did this by swapping values because of the way you implemented this tree.  If this were a true binary tree with left and right you could just dump nodes to the left and right and sort them that way.

Comment: Maybe add a return after leftChild.addLeft(subtree); otherwise you will overwrite your leftChild at the end.

Comment: Thank you both. I implemented @AlanKlaassen method correction and then the return suggested by Andreas, and it fixed my issue.

Comment: That would have been a simpler fix, I noticed right after posting that there was an issue with it and rewrote it again.  I'm glad it worked for you though!